# how to export Reflect.defineProperty()?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

So I've been using a bunch of these in my main javascript initiation file, there's like 20-30 of these that I need. Is there a way that I can export these from a different files so I can clear up my main file?

```
Reflect.defineProperty(numerator, 'getBalance', {
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const TEMPLATEUser = numerator.get(id);
        return TEMPLATEUser ? TEMPLATEUser.balance : 0;
    },
});
```

Comment: Reflect.defineProperty is a global function, so it should be accessible anywhere. Do you mean you want to export the whole call above?

Comment: @NguyễnViệtĐức yes i want to export the entire call. in total, all my calls take up around 2,000 lines of code and it's highly inefficient.

Comment: So you want to have a function which takes an object as input and define a property named get which is the getBalance function?

Comment: @DucNguyen ugh sorry i got it wrong; i edited it. what exactly i want to do is create an export for that entire block (including the Reflect.defineProperty) and import it into my main javascript file.

Comment: @DucNguyen thanks that answer works, but is there a way that i can use so that i can constantly swap out TEMPLATEUser??

let's say i want a.getBalance() and b.getBalance(), but one of them as AUser and the other needs BUser.

Comment: In your code I see that TEMPLATEUser is retrieved from the object itself. So for a it should be AUser, and for b it should be BUser. Can you explain clearer what you mean?

Comment: @DucNguyen So, I have multiple of these defineProperties, and they're used to define different balances on a User. For example, AUser and BUser could be the same person, but they're used to retrieve currency A and currency B respectively. I'm trying to integrate both currency A and currency B into one defineProperties statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a function to abstract away what you're doing. Suppose you define this function in a file called `file1.js` and you want to use it in `file2.js`.

```js
// file1.js
module.exports.defineGetBalance = obj => {
    Reflect.defineProperty(obj, 'getBalance', {
        value: function getBalance(id) {
            const TEMPLATEUser = obj.get(id);
            return TEMPLATEUser ? TEMPLATEUser.balance : 0;
        },
    });
};
```

Now you can call `defineGetBalance()` as many times as you can, you just have to pass the object you want to assign that `getBalance` function into.

```js
// file2.js
const { defineGetBalance } = require('./file1');

// ...
defineGetBlance(obj1);
defineGetBlance(obj2);

// now both obj1 and obj2 have a getBalance() function
const balance1 = obj1.getBalance(id1)
const balance2 = obj2.getBalance(id2)

// you a for loop if you can
for (const obj of arrObj) {
    defineGetBalance(obj);
}

// ...
```